# Send SMS with Twilio - add line break

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, twilio

I would like to add a line break in the text message and tried both
**\n** and **%0a** as suggested in this article:
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181468-How-do-I-Add-a-Line-Break-in-my-SMS-or-MMS-Message-

```
sendSms("+123456789", "line1%0aline2");
sendSms("+123456789", "line1\nline2");
```

However, when I received the message, I still see the new line characters, they are not getting replaced by a line break.

```
function sendSms(to, body) {
  var messages_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/YOURACCOUNTSID/Messages.json";

  var payload = {
    "To": to,
    "Body" : body,
    "From" : "YOURTWILIONUMBER"
  };

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  };

  options.headers = { 
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("YOURACCOUNTSID:YOURAUTHTOKEN")
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
}
```

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/send-sms-from-a-google-spreadsheet.html

Comment: It would make sense to reach out to their support if a feature they claim to work is not working.

Comment: @toms You should try with HTML <br>  tags 
I hope It works for you

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple: I entered a new line in a cell by pressing alt + enter. This is then interpreted by Twilio as New Line and transmitted as such.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Twilio you can add line break using "\n" with string. And It's 100% working I was Implemented.**

Try like this example:

sendSms("+123456789", 'line1' + '\n' + 'line2' +'\n'+ 'line3');

output like:

line1
line2
line3